# installing packages from usb to ubuntu server 14.04

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I want to install these packages to my Ubuntu server from USB as i have tried many thing by editing mirrors in `/etc/apt/sources.list` to install some packages for Ubuntu server 14.04 know I want to try installing them from USB so would any one guide me how should I?

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential libacl1-dev libattr1-dev libblkid-dev libgnutls-dev libreadline-dev python-dev python-dnspython gdb pkg-config libpopt-dev libldap2-dev dnsutils libbsd-dev attr krb5-user docbook-xsl libcups2-dev libpam0g-dev ntp -y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have all those packages downloaded as .deb files (you did not say, if you don't have them you can get any packages from the [Ubuntu repo](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) here) on your USB, copy them to a folder we will call it `packages` and put it in `/home`, or you can just change to the USB if you know its path

```
mkdir packages
```

Put all your `.debs` in here and change to the directory

```
cd ~/packages
```

Then run

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

To install all .deb files in the folder, to resolve dependencies

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: how should i download these packages to my usb ??

Comment: from where should i download .deb files??

Comment: That should be your question, not how to install them, anyway, you can find all repo packages here http://packages.ubuntu.com/, I will update the answer to reflect this, Can I ask, what was wrong with your apt-get command ? Was there an error ? Might be quicker too fix that, rather than download loads of .debs. Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

"dpkg -i yourpackage.deb" should do the job if I understand your question properly - once you have your USB memory stick mounted with the .deb files of your choice.

Comment: how should i download these packages to my usb ??